# Tooltip not working in angular component test (from ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I was using TooltipModule from ng2-bootstrap and recently switched to ngx-bootstrap. Tooltips work fine in my application - no issues. However, in my Angular component test, when I import the following:

```
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

and then in the TestBed, Import the following:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot(),
```

Tooltips are not rendered. I dont see the tooltip in dev console under Elements tab in my browser.
When I use the import from ng2-bootstrap as:

```
import { TooltipModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

everything works fine. I see the tooltip rendered.

What is the issue here? Tooltip works fine in my app. Only in Angular test, I am having issues. Do I need to do anything differently or extra in my tests to make tooltips work from ngx-bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

you have to import import 
`{ TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';`

in your relative module like `app.module` not in your component and then in your modules import array add `TooltipModule.forRoot()`.

that's it you can use tooltip now in your `app.modules` components.

If you are using lazy-loading then add `{ TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';` it  in your other module.

Comment: **If you are using lazy-loading then add { TooltipModule } in your other lazy-loaded module** This is very important

Answer (score 1):

this is what we do (tests are really old, but still working)

```
it('tooltip should be displayed by focus event after 0 ms by default',
fakeAsync(() => {
  const element: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  const tooltipElement: any = element.querySelector('#test-tooltip1');
  tooltipElement.focus();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick(0);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(element.querySelector('.tooltip-inner')).not.toBeNull();
})
);
```

full sample can be found here: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/31c5f62a48560d4372f0043241829a27e5f3deb6/src/spec/tooltip.directive.spec.ts#L66-L77